# Force HTML select element to use user agent css and arrow image

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-agent

I have html element for example..

```
<select>  
   <option>1</option>  
   <option>2</option>   
   <option>3</option> 
</select>
```

which has some element css applied on it..for example..

```
select {
         background-image: url(//arrow.png);//this is arrow image
       }
```

now i don't want to use above background image of arrow for my select tag ..i want to use the default user agent arrow (background-image css) for select Element so do we have any way ?? so that we can force element to use default user agent means (IE,chrome,firefox) arrow image and its default css.

Comment: show the styled CSS you are working with, because I suspect it's an :before or :after element

Comment: @Tschallacka its not working for the ie browser?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the property value initial for the the changed properties?

```css
select {
        border-radius: 0;
        background-color: red;
        background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/3DYU6.png');
       }

select.default {
  border-radius: initial;
  background-color: initial;
  background-image: none;
  }
```

```html
<select class="default">  
   <option>1</option>  
   <option>2</option>   
   <option>3</option> 
</select>
<select>  
   <option>1</option>  
   <option>2</option>   
   <option>3</option> 
</select>
```

[Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#search=initial) statistics for this feature:
[image]

Comment: Support: not IE<=11, OK for Edge and other major browsers according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=initial)

Comment: Thanks @FelipeAls added it in the answer

Comment: update your question with the specifics you wish, and bacground-image usually is :none on a select list. updated my answer

Comment: when i am doing background image : none then its not showing arrow itself.

Comment: See this answer where the styling you wish to disable is done